# Powershell search-string inside a variable (not text file)

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to search for a string called "Hostname" from a variable "$a" which stores the output of "systeminfo" command but ran into issues. I am using "system-info" to gather a bigger set of data.

**Code:**

```
$a= (get-systeminfo -computername localhost | select-object hostname, OSNAME, osversion, model, type)  
write-output $a 
select-string $a -pattern "hostname"
```

**Error:**

```
Select-String : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\john001c\@{Hostname=PACCPL-FTN1TM1; OSName=Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise ; OSVersion=6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601; Model=Latitude E
4310; Type=x64-based PC}' because it does not exist.

At line:5 char:14
+ select-string <<<<  $a -pattern "hostname"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\john...e=x64-based PC}:String) [Select-String], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

What is the correct way to search for a string inside a variable?

Comment: Why not just use `get-content env:computername` to get the host name instead of parsing SystemInfo?

Comment: Also, I attempted to format your question a little better, please edit it further and correct the code section (if needed), as I'm not sure the line breaks turned out right.

Comment: `$a | select-string "hostname"`

Answer (score 4):

[Select-string](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) has multiple parameter sets.  To search within an object (instead of a file) your parameters would look like this.  Note the use of the `-InputObject` parameter is required for usage against something that isn't a file, and it isn't usable as a positional paramater, the `-InputObject` parameter must be explicitly named.

> Parameter Set: Object
>   Select-String [-Pattern]  -InputObject

So try this intead.

```
select-string -pattern "hostname" -InputObject $a
```

Comment: how will I find a string in string and return it's position?